# Update a MS Word file to SQL Server being in a datagridview from C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, ms-word, datagridview, sql-update

I would like to modify a file in the bd SQL Server

I am designing a C# application that stores word files in a SQL Server database but I like to open the files from my datagridview and save changes coming from MS Word.

Comment: You are going to need to be more specific about what you are talking about.  For example, what's _the bd SQL Server_?  You won't get an answer unless you describe in detail (preferably with code (much preferably)) what this means: _o open the files from my datagridview and save changes coming from MS Word._

Comment: I created an interaction between c# and my sql server database.  I am storing microsoft word files which are displayed in my datagridview.  and now I would like to modify these words files located in my database.  THANKS

Comment: I would like to modify them from Microsoft word

Comment: A general plan would be to load data from sql server, save it as temporary file, open the file in word, watch for file changes and save the data back. One problem is that you won't know when user is done with the file. Well, unless you're using automation to connect to the word instance but that's a bit more complicated. Perhaps easier just to write back the file after some grace period

Comment: how can i do that?

Comment: Break down each part and then do it? For loading binary to a file from sql server, there are tons of answers here on SO for instance

Comment: can you do it for me?  if possible reproduce the code etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is less an answer than it is an extended comment.  First, we don't *"do it for [you]... if possible reproduce the code etc."*.  We help you by answering questions about coding that you ask, preferably by you showing us your code and asking questions about that.

But, here's an attempt to answer what you are looking for.  I'm assuming this is Windows Forms (there's a `winforms` tag you can use on your question, by the way).  My assumption is based on your reference to `DataGridView`.

By the way, a SQL Server database doesn't store *files*.  It can store blobs of stuff that would normally be in a file, but not files.  In what you seem to be describing, it's likely going to be storing OpenXML data that would normally be  in a `.docx` file.

I'm guessing that you are trying to build a Windows Forms app that has a DataGridView (DGV).  Each row of the grid will represent one of your database-resident *"files"*.  It will have some metadata (like the *"filename"*) and a control (likely a button) that will act to open the *"file"* in Word.

To do this, you will need to copy the blob of file data out of your database row and create an actual (temporary) file somewhere, and then start Word, pointing it to your newly created file.

The .NET Framework provides you with two tools you can use at this point.

1. When you start up another process, you get a reference to the process, and you can set things up so that you can be notified with the process ends.  This way, you can tell when your user exits Word.  Now, Microsoft tends to do *special* things with their applications, so this may require some finesse.
2. There's something in the Framework known as a `FileSystemWatcher`.  You can point it at a file and you will be notified whenever that file is updated or deleted.

What you want to do with this information is really up to you.  After this, it is, as @siggemannen said in the comments, just a matter of figuring out what the parts of this are, and then writing code to implement those parts.  Remember, if you have issues with your code, come back here, show us your code, and get answers.

**Update:**

You're begging me to write your software for you.  That's not how this site works (and, I work for a living and don't have time to do your work).  But, this should help.

1. Create a table in SQL Server that has one column to store the contents of your Word "document".  That column should be capable of storing a *Blob* (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/blob/binary-large-object-blob-data-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver16).  Have at least one other column for metadata (a filename, perhaps).
2. Populate that table with at least two rows (two file).
3. Write a Windows Forms app with a grid.  Select the metadata from your table and show it in some sort of grid or list.  The UI should include a button for each row.
4. When someone clicks the rows button:

   - Select the blob data for that row
   - Write it out to a temporary file (use the TEMP environment variable to find a good place - use a name that's not to obvious, but that ends in `.docx`)
   - Use a FileSystemWatcher to monitor that file for changes
   - Use System.Diagnostics.Process (using the Shell) to start that document up, opening it in Word
   - Using the Process object that you got when you started up your document, and hook up an `Exited` event handler.
5. Decide what you want to do with the events from the FileSystemWatcher and the Exited event.  You could update the data in the database on every change, or simply monitor the file for changes and update it when Word exits.  You likely want to delete the temporary file while the Exited event happens.

There you go.

Comment: can i have a tutorial for this??  Please

Comment: Help me Flydog57

Comment: Thanks a lot.  I have already created the sql database and the windows form application and my data is displayed in my datagridview and there is the button to open my word data but I don't know so far how to save these changes with this  FileSystemWatcher